# Reading Multiple Email Headers with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am creating a small application to read email headers.The output is "undefined." Is there a specific coding error, and how can I fix it?

```
function test() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,5)
  var messages = threads[0].getMessages();
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(messages.getRawContent);

  }
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to dereference the array returned by `.getMessages()`, is all:

```
Logger.log(messages[i].getRawContent);
                   ^^^
```